# vba get text from webpage and display as message in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am using the following code in vba to extract a value from a website.

Let's pretend the value is wrapped inside a html span id. i want to retrieve this value and display it as a message box in excel.

Here's my code:

```
Sub PullExpiry()

    Dim IE As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Site.aspx?BrcSiteCode=" & Range("J6").Value

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    Dim dd As String
    dd = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")(0).innerText

    MsgBox dd

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""



End Sub
```

HTML:

```
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate">Expiry Date : 16/02/2018</span>
```

I get an object doesn't support this property or method error:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")(0).innerText
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

EDIT

```
Other code tried:

Sub PullExpiry()

    Dim IE As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
    IE.Visible = False

    ' URL to get data from
    IE.Navigate "https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Site.aspx?BrcSiteCode=" & Range("J6").Value

    ' Statusbar
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading, Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.StatusBar = "Searching for value. Please wait..."

    Dim dd As String
    dd = IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")(0).innerText
    MsgBox dd

    ' Show IE
    IE.Visible = True

    ' Clean up
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.StatusBar = ""



End Sub
```

Comment: did you checked for another website / className ? the code works ok  for  for http://stackoverflow.com classname='summary' for example

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the html and highlight the area you wish to extract?

Comment: Is it in a span? I remember something when scraping a web site once, that you cant have text in a span, or something like that.

Comment: `Do While IE.Busy` also worth checking the `readystate` as well.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Please see updated question with HTML

Comment: have you tried innerHTML?

Comment: `Application.Wait` is an unreliable way to wait, just use `DoEvents` instead. Also, if you're using a recent version of IE9+ you can use `getElementByID` method, since ID is a unique identifier.

Comment: that's it, its the ID not the class name. :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav thanks tried ready state and it just seemed to make it crash

Comment: @Nathan_Sav tried InnerHtml and it produces error object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: @Nathan_Sav but if i change ClassName to ID it produces another object variable or with block variable not set  error

Comment: break it down then, say `set e=ie.document.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")` then `s=e.innerText` see, even go back to checking IE, you can use the locals window to help to.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks ive tried  what you said in my code, see edit. Bit gives me an automation error on this line dd = IE.Document.getElementByID("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FormView1_GridView1_ctl02_lb_ExpiryDate")(0).innerText

Comment: there's no `(0)` if you use `getElementID` because that method only/always returns either a single element (as long as it exists).

Comment: Also, when debugging, you need to stop chaining your methods & properties in order to determine where the error is. First, see if `getElementById` returns an object. Use @Nathan_Sav 's suggestion to do this.